# What is the serial number of a partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, partitioning

Executing `vol` in the command prompt shows the "Volume Serial Number".

What actually is that serial number of a partition and what is its use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source - [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number)

> A volume serial number is a serial
>   number assigned to a disk volume or
>   tape volume. It originated in 1950s in
>   mainframe computer operating systems.
>   In OS/360 line it is
>   human-configurable, has a maximum
>   length of six characters, is in
>   uppercase, must start with a letter,
>   and identifies a volume to the system
>   in unique manner. For example "SYSRES"
>   is often used for a system residence
>   volume.
>
> In FAT and NTFS file systems, a volume
>   serial number is a feature used to
>   determine if a disk is present in a
>   drive or not, and to detect if it was
>   exchanged with another one. This
>   identification system was created by
>   Microsoft and IBM during their
>   development of OS/2.
>
> The FAT/NTFS serial number is a 32-bit
>   number determined by the date on the
>   current computer at the time of a
>   disk's formatting. Previously, the
>   method used to discern whether a disk
>   was swapped was reading its volume
>   label. However, it was not required to
>   be unique or even non-empty. Many
>   users had not given disks any name.

In `extN` and several other filesystems, the serial number is a 128-bit randomly generated UUID.

Comment: Yup, these days, it is usually used as a component of uniquely identifying a system, mostly for copy-protection systems. For example, when you buy a program, the developer may assign you a serial number based on a hardware key, which includes the volume serial number as part of the its calculation, in order to lock it to your system.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful for persistence with removable devices in particular.

I have 2 apps that make use of that value.

One is a backup application that uses the serial in the path rather than the mountpoint, which helps keep rotations in line.

Another is a mountpoint reservation app that provides functionality for Windows similarly to that of the UUID syntax in linux's fstab mountpoint configuration.